# Properly using mapActionsToProps in a functional component (react-redux)

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

```
const updateRouterArr = () => {
    if (this.props.router_addr && this.props.router_username && this.props.router_pw) {
        this.props.updateRouterArr({
            router_addr: this.props.router_addr,
            router_username: this.props.router_username,
            router_pw: this.props.router_pw
        })
    } else {
        alert('Some fields are missing')
    }
}

export const RouterCard = (props) => {
    return (
        <div>
            ...
        </div>
    );
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    routers: state.router.routers,
    router_addr: state.router.router_addr,
    router_username: state.router.router_username,
    router_pw: state.router.router_pw,
})

const mapActionsToProps = {
    updateRouterElem: updateRouterElem,
    updateRouterArr: updateRouterArr,
    deleteRouterElem: deleteRouterElem,
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapActionsToProps)(RouterCard);
```

I am using a functional component with React-Redux. When I tried this, it gave me `Parsing error: Identifier 'updateRouterArr' has already been declared`

I get why that is happening, but I am not sure about how to properly use React-Redux when using a functional component.

I've declared all actions that I need in

```
const mapActionsToProps = {
    updateRouterElem: updateRouterElem,
    updateRouterArr: updateRouterArr,
    deleteRouterElem: deleteRouterElem,
}
```

but it's quite confusing since it does not recognize `this.props` anymore.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Either move the Redux wiring with `connect` to another file (like in a `index.js` or a `YourComponentContainer.jsx` file beside this one) or just alias the action when importing it. `import { updateRouterArr as updateRouterArrAction } from 'yourReduxActionFile';`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just don't need `this.` before `props`. Functional component will receive props as argument.

So code will look like

```
// Assuming that updateRouterArr is global function
const updateRouterArr = (props) => {
    if (props.router_addr && props.router_username && props.router_pw) {
        props.updateRouterArr({
            router_addr: props.router_addr,
            router_username: props.router_username,
            router_pw: props.router_pw
        })
    } else {
        alert('Some fields are missing')
    }
}

export const RouterCard = (props) => {
    // And you can call it from RouterCard component
    updateRouterArr(props);
    return (
        <div>
            ...
        </div>
    );
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    routers: state.router.routers,
    router_addr: state.router.router_addr,
    router_username: state.router.router_username,
    router_pw: state.router.router_pw,
})

const mapActionsToProps = {
    updateRouterElem: updateRouterElem,
    updateRouterArr: updateRouterArr,
    deleteRouterElem: deleteRouterElem,
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapActionsToProps)(RouterCard);
```

And simple [example](https://codesandbox.io/s/funccomponentwithredux-bvzdj)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this whether this helps. I have made some changes in mapActionsToProps and I have use object destructuring for getting the props. Props can be accessed by same names.

```
const updateRouterArr = (
{updateRouterElem, updateRouterArr, deleteRouterElem, routers, router_addr, router_username, router_pw}
) => {
    if (router_addr && router_username && router_pw) {
        updateRouterArr({
            router_addr: router_addr,
            router_username: router_username,
            router_pw: router_pw
        })
    } else {
        alert('Some fields are missing')
    }
}

export const RouterCard = (props) => {
    return (
        <div>
            ...
        </div>
    );
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    routers: state.router.routers,
    router_addr: state.router.router_addr,
    router_username: state.router.router_username,
    router_pw: state.router.router_pw,
})

const mapActionsToProps = {
    updateRouterElem,
    updateRouterArr,
    deleteRouterElem,
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapActionsToProps)(RouterCard);
```