# mapActionsToProps Functional component vs Class

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

Have a Class Component that mapActionsToProp and works just fine -

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import {logoutUser} from '../Redux/Actions/userActions'


export class notFound extends Component {
  handleLogout =() => {
    this.props.logoutUser();
};
  render() {

    const { user: { credentials: { handle}}} = this.props;
        return (
        <div className='body' style={Styles.body}>
           <div className='loaderPanel' style={Styles.loaderPanel}>
             <div className='loaderPanelInner' style= 
  {Styles.loaderPanelInner}>
                <div className='Welcome' style={Styles.welcome}>
                  <h1> What are you doing {handle}!! </h1>
                  <p>You are definitely lost...</p> <br />
                  <p>You have come to a "404 Page Not Found", Error 
Page</p> <br />
               <p>Maybe you should head back to some safer 
waters</p>
               <Link to="/" onClick={this.handleLogout} >go 
back</Link>
                </div>
             </div>
           </div>
         </div>
        )
   }
 }

 const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
   user: state.user
});
const mapActionsToProps = {
   logoutUser
}
export default connect(mapStateToProps,mapActionsToProps) 
(notFound );
```

The Above imports the logoutUser and then uses it in a function that is called onClick. I am trying to do the same but in a functional component. Something like this-

```
import React from 'react'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'

import {logoutUser} from '../Redux/Actions/userActions'
const notFound = (user) => {

  const handleLogout = (logoutUser) => {
    logoutUser.logoutUser()
    };

  const { user: { credentials: {handle}}} = user;
return (
<div className='body' style={Styles.body}>
 <div className='loaderPanel' style={Styles.loaderPanel}>
 <div className='loaderPanelInner' style={Styles.loaderPanelInner}>
 <div className='Welcome' style={Styles.welcome}>
   <h1> What are you doing {handle}!! </h1>
   <p>You are definitely lost...</p> <br />
   <p>You have come to a "404 Page Not Found", Error Page</p>
   <br />
   <p>Maybe you should head back to some safer waters</p>
 <button onClick={handleLogout}>Change check1</button>
 </div>
 </div>
 </div>   
 </div>
  )
 }
const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    user: state.user
})
const mapActionsToProps = {
  logoutUser: logoutUser
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps,mapActionsToProps) 
(notFound);
```

Sorry for the bad formatting the first time but its really about how to implement the mapActionsToProp in a functional component.
Cheers and thanks for the help again

Comment: Can you provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?  This code will not work; you never closed the notFound function and the formatting is unreadable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The right answer here is: **use the React-Redux hooks API ( `useSelector` and `useDispatch` )** , rather than the legacy `connect` API.

We teach how to use the hooks in our Redux core docs tutorials:

- https://redux.js.org/tutorials/essentials/part-2-app-structure
- https://redux.js.org/tutorials/fundamentals/part-5-ui-react

Comment: Thanks for the advice. UseSelector and useDispatch both allow you to read and make calls to the store which is unfortunately not what i am looking to do. The function "logoutUser" lives in the userActions.js file which makes the calls to evoke the change in the store. Maybe like you say there is a more elegant way but for now i just need to make the call from mapActionToProps. I know it can be done as I have seen some complicated examples(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57259369/properly-using-mapactionstoprops-in-a-functional-component-react-redux) I just seem to be missing something.

Comment: In that case I'm really not clear what the actual question is - can you clarify what you are _trying_ to do exactly, and what specifically isn't working?  The process of actually dispatching works the same in the end, it's just a question of how the component code has access to `dispatch`.

Comment: In the Class code I can use “this.prop.logoutUser()” in the handleLogout function because it’s imported and defined in mapActionsToProps! In the Functional component I can not. Just want to know how to call the “logoutUser()” function that lives in userActions.js properly. I tried to call it like a hook by setting it as a “const logout = logoutUser();” and then just calling “logout()” in handleLogout but it works and then throws a weird “dispatch is not a function” error as it sends “dispatch type: SET_UNAUTHENTICATED”! Does not have an error when called from the Class component. Thanks

Comment: There is no `this` in a function component. Instead of `this.props`, a function component gets all of its props as its only argument - `function MyComponent(props) { }`.  So, if you're using `connect`, it would just be `props.logoutUser()`.  If you're using the hooks API, you'd do `const dispatch = useDispatch()` to get the hook, and then `dispatch(logoutUser())` in a click handler.  Please read the tutorial pages I linked to see how.

Comment: O-kee-doh-kee… tried all that was suggesting and didn’t work! The issue was that I was trying to pass “const notFound = (user,props)….” In my attempts. I’m such an idiot as it only takes “props” which holds both the state and the prop from mapActionsToProps for what I was passing!(good ol’ console.logging)! Figured it was something super simple! Thanks for taking the time to help 

Answer (score 0):

This is just to help anyone like me to get up to speed converting a Class Component to Functional where you need to map state and Actions to prop.
Below is the working code as a functional component.

```
import React from 'react'
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';
import { connect } from 'react-redux'

import {logoutUser} from '../Redux/Actions/userActions'

const NotFound = (props) => {
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  const handleLogout = () => {
    navigate(-1);
    props.logoutUser();
    };

  const { credentials: {handle}} = props.user;

  return (
    <div className='body' style={Styles.body}>
      <div className='loaderPanel' style={Styles.loaderPanel}>
        <div className='loaderPanelInner' style={Styles.loaderPanelInner}>
          <div className='Welcome' style={Styles.welcome}>
             <h1> What are you doing {handle}!! </h1>
             <p>You are definitely lost...</p> <br />
             <h3>You have come to a "404 Page Not Found", Error Page</h3> 
             <br />
             <p>Maybe you should head back to some safer waters</p>
             <button onClick={handleLogout}>go back</button>
           </div>
          </div>
         </div>
       </div>
  )
}
const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    user: state.user
});
const mapActionsToProps = {
  logoutUser
};
 export default connect(mapStateToProps,mapActionsToProps)(NotFound);
```

Most everyone else will read and say "Dah! this is obvious"; but it may just help someone out. And all the other examples I found were more complex than this which made it hard for at least my little brain to follow;)